# how to make specific model field dynamic from another model

Tags: django, django-models, orm

I have two models Damaged and Product.In the Product model the quantity of the product depends upon the value of damaged_quantity which is stored in another table.For example if the damaged_quantity is in damaged table then the value of quantity in product should be `quantity-damaged_quantity` if the `damaged.product_id == product.id` .I tried like this but it is not working

> models.py

```
class Damaged(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    damaged_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

> views.py I access the queryset of product like this in my views

```
def list_products(request):
products = Product.objects.annotate(damaged_product_quantity=Sum('damagedproducts__damaged_quantity')).annotate(
        real_quantity=ExpressionWrapper(F('quantity') - F('damaged_product_quantity'), output_field=IntegerField()))
```

> list_product_template. Here while displaying the real_quantity if the damage.damaged_quanity and the product.quantity  are euqal then it doesnot changes the value.Instead of becomming Zero it doesnot change the value.In other case it is working fine.

```
                {% if not product.real_quantity %}
                {{product.quantity}}
                {% elif product.real_quantity == product.quantity %}
                 0
                {% else %}
                {{ product.real_quantity }}
                {% endif %}
```

> product_detail page

```
def product_detail(request, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug)
    damaged = Damaged.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'pos/product_detail.html', {'product': product,'damaged':damaged})
```

> product_detail template.I tried like this to get the current quantity of products after adding damaged_products but it is nt working well.It is giving me both `{% if %}` and `{% else %}` part.How can i solve this?

```
product quantity:
{% for damage in damaged %}
{% if product.id == damage.product_id %}
{{product.quantity|subtract:damage.damaged_quantity}}
{% else %}
{{product.quantity}}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I believe it's better to have a property not a field for your purpose: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#model-methods

Comment: i used save method because i wanted to change in database also.I suppose using property does not do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to override the save method in `Damaged` model:

```
class Damaged(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    damaged_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Damaged, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.product.quantity = self.product.quantity - self.damaged_quantity
        self.product.save()
```

But this solution might be inconsistent. For example, if you try to update the Damaged model, then value of the product will be updated again.

I would recommend using [**`annotation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation) to attach value with Product, so that you can query if needed. For example:

For this, lets add a [**`related_name`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) field in `Damaged` model:

```
class Damaged(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='damagedproducts')
    damaged_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Usage:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, F, IntegerField

products = Product.objects.annotate(damaged_product_quantity=Sum('damagedproducts__damaged_quantity')).annotate(real_quantity=ExpressionWrapper(F('quantity') - F('damaged_product_quantity'), output_field=IntegerField())

real_quantity_more_than_ten = products.filter(real_quantity__gt=10)

for p in real_quantity_more_than_ten:
    print(p.real_quantity)
```

### Update

```
from django.db.models import Sum

def product_detail(request, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug)
    damaged = product.productdamaged.all()
    if damaged.exists():
       damage_amount = damaged.aggregate(d_amount = Sum('productdamaged__damaged_quantity')).get('d_amount', 0)
    else:
      damage_amount = 0

    return render(request, 'pos/product_detail.html', {'product': product,'damage_amount':damage_amount})

# template

{% if damage_amount != 0 %}
   {{product.quantity|subtract:damage_amount}}
{% else %}
   {{product.quantity}}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I am not changing the product quantity. I have added a new attribute `real_quantity` which will show the actual quantity of products after deducing damaged ones

Comment: when the damaged_quantity is equal to product_quantity the value in products table doesn't become zero. How to solve this??

Comment: one last question.i have edited my question from your solution.Now i want some little changes.Can you help me ??

Comment: @SugAt please see the update section. You are seeing if and else both because there could be multiple damage for a single product.

Comment: Thanks, and what about when damaged_quantity is equal to product_quantity the value in list_products.html template not becoming `0`.

Comment: I will look further into that, but right now I think you have a workable solution :)